# How do i give option to a terminal command running through go script?

Tags: go, centos, redhat, yum

Lets suppose I have a go script which invokes the command

`yum install packagename`.

It comes to a point where it asks `y/n` to install the package, there is `--assumeyes` option in yum (in this case) which i dont want to use.

Is there any other way in `go` to send `y` to the command as i dont want to give the `y` manually when running the script

Answer (score 3):

The `y` is inputted via `stdin`. When you launch a subprocess, you give it a writer where you can write to its `stdin`.

The os/exec docs have an [example](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_StdinPipe).

Comment: can you help me with an example?

Comment: I added a link to one